# Openlayers map.removeControl() error

Tags: openlayers

I cant remove editingToolBar from the map. I dont understand why this code is not working:

```
var editingToolBar = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
    displayClass: 'customEditingToolbar',
    allowDepress: true
}); 

var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    newShape, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
    {
       title: "Draw Feature",
       displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
       multi: true
    }
);

var edit = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(newShape, {
    title: "Modify Feature",
    displayClass: "olControlModifyFeature"
});

editingToolBar.addControls([edit, draw]);
map.addControl(editingToolBar);

function stopEditing(){
    map.removeControl(editingToolBar);
}
```

Thank you for debugging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, the error is that editingToolBar variable was not defined as global, but inside a function, so not accessible in stopEditing() function.

Defining the var in global:

```
var editingToolBar;
```